# Standard deviation of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Since dataframe.std() is deprecated, we should use groupby now: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.std.html

However, for finding a simple standard deviation of this

```
dataframe['number'].std(),
```

the groupby function seems to be an unnecessarily long command to me. "dataframe" has a column of 'number' ranging from 1 to 100.

What would the above line look like using groupby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding of the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.std.html).

What pandas is deprecating is specifically the `level` parameter in favor of its [groupby counterpart](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.std.html) (the link you shared). Nowhere it says `pandas.Series.std` is deprecated as a whole:

> level: int or level name, default None
> If the axis is a MultiIndex (hierarchical), count along a particular level, collapsing into a scalar.
>
> > Deprecated since version 1.3.0: The level keyword is deprecated. Use groupby instead.

and:

> numeric_only: bool, default None
> Include only float, int, boolean columns. If None, will attempt to use everything, then use only numeric data. Not implemented for Series.
>
> > Deprecated since version 1.5.0: Specifying numeric_only=None is deprecated. The default value will be False in a future version of pandas.

Given the line of code you propose, I see no reason for changing it. Keep using:

```
df['col'].std()
```